# How to make this .htaccess rule case insensitive?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, case-insensitive

This is a rule in my .htaccess

```
# those CSV files are under the DOCROOT ... so let's hide 'em
<FilesMatch "\.CSV$">
 Order Allow,Deny
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

I've noticed however that if there is a file with a lowercase or mixed case extension of CSV, it will be ignored by the rule and displayed.

How do I make this case insensitive?

I hope it doesn't come down to  `"\.(?:CSV|csv)$"` (which I'm not sure would even work, and doesn't cover all bases)

**Note:** The files are under the docroot, and are uploaded automatically there by a 3rd party service, so I'd prefer to implement a rule my end instead of bothering them. Had *I* set this site up though, I'd go for above the docroot.

Thanks

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[This page from the apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/sections.html#file-and-web) says that you can do it like this:

```
<FilesMatch \.(?i:csv)$>
```

Comment: This syntax also works with 'or' statements: `"\.(?i:gif|jpe?g|png)$"`

Answer (score 21):

Case insensitive:

```
<FilesMatch "(?i)\.(js|css|eot|ttf)$">
```

Answer (score 0):

`"\.[cC][sS][vV]$"`

It is still probably better to be consistent and rename the uploaded files as they arrive on your server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer mate, but that's a bit hacky.

Comment: My scenario is to validate upper or lower case in query string. This solution suites. Thank you @Amy