# Mod_spelling and limited access to certain files through htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, case-sensitive

We have enabled spelling mod by default on our server to avoid linking problems with html code done on Windows. Recently we added protection to our image folder to allow only images and documents of certain type to be accesible through htaccess by simple deny,allow and list of allowed types:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
<Files ~ ".(jpe?g|png|gif|pdf)$">
Allow from all
</Files>
```

Problem is, that now images with wrong case in url, which are supposed to be corrected with mod-spelling, shows error (Forbidden access) instead of actual image. Any ideas how to correct this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520566/how-to-make-this-htaccess-rule-case-insensitive